# How to disable confirmation mail when a user changes his e-mail in Wordpress with Buddypress

Tags: php, wordpress, email, buddypress, confirmation

I have a website with Wordpress and Buddypress installed in it. The Wordpress version is 5.2.1. and the Buddypress pluggin is updated.

I'm using Buddypress as an Intranet (not as a social network), so I have loaded all the users through a .csv file and the user e-mail is not the real one (for example, if the username is pperezlopez, the e-mail is pperezlopez@testemail.com).

All the users have to change their e-mails, but when they try to do it, it appears the message "There is a pending change in the e-mail addres to xxxxxx. Check your e-mail () to get the verification link or cancel the pending change" (something like that).
Here you have a screenshot: https://prnt.sc/o0veqp

I have tried this code into functions.php file, but it doesn't work. 
add_filter( 'wcfm_is_allow_email_verification', '__return_false' );

Obviously, they don't have access to that fake e-mails, so they can't change them.

Any idea, please? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Why don't you just add them with their real email addresses?

Comment: Is there not a standard format of email address based off their users names?  Could you not add aliases for the email address that match the user names?

Comment: It's not so easy... :)
The intranet is for a High School and there are new teachers every year; the "Board of Education" provide us the name and surnames of every teacher but the  the responsible of the Intranet can't be asking for the e-mail of each teacher. But he/she can

Comment: load the names, usernames and departments with a "fake" email (because it's compulsory).
So I thought that it would be easier if the teachers, with an username and password easy to remember (the initial letter of his/her name and the surnames), could log into the Intranet and change the e-mail.
Did I make it clear?

Comment: Any other idea? Thank you in advance!